# Application Background in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, interface, background

Please help me! My App Background won't appear on my mobile device upon running the project.
What might be the problem? I already lessen the resolution of my background image but still no progress. The output won't appear. But if I remove the background it would appear instantly.

Here's the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:contentDescription="@string/my_logo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mr_hertz"
        android:id="@+id/mr"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mr_hertz_"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="290dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/account"
        android:id="@+id/account"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mr"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/my_account" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/member_"
        android:textColor="#f0fffc"
        android:id="@+id/member"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_below="@+id/account"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sign_in"
        android:id="@+id/sign"
        android:contentDescription="@string/sign_in_"
        android:layout_below="@+id/member"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/member"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/member" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you explain more. what's is hided when you set the background ??

Comment: empty the layout with the imageviews, and textviews etc. Do you see the background ---  (290dp) for a logo in an imageview sounds a bit too high in dp

Comment: Hi, I tried emptying the layout aside from the background and it works. The background appears perfectly. Do i need to change its resolution?

Answer (score 0):

If your entire layout is empty, try removing:

```
tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

Otherwise, if your view appears correctly in the Graphical Layout part of the editor, something is wrong with your image. Try using another.

Comment: No. That shouldn't be a problem. Is the rest of the layout appearing?

Comment: yes, it now appears!. but the problem is the compatibility with my android phone. It does not fit like what appears in the preview.